# Outlook 2010 - How can I create/amend what appear to be a shortcut

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

A previous employee created what appear to be shortcuts for things that she did everyday in Outlook, both in Calendar and Email, e.g.

When she typed **QA** (for Quote Appointment) in a new calendar appointment it would show as:

- Name:
- Phone:
- Address:
- Email:
- Description:
- Source:

Then she would fill in those descriptions as she was talking to a customer on the phone.
Can someone please explain in detail how this is done, where we I find the shortcut in order to change it and then share it among other new employees, please?

Comment: Likely, it was Auto-correct. Unfortunately, my organization doesn't use Outlook, so I can't give a step-by-step, although I used to do the same type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this is most likely done through auto-correct.

This is a feature of Word rather than Outlook but Outlook uses Word as a rich editor. The autocorrect dialogue is well hidden in Outlook and I generally add it to a convenient ribbon. However, you can also find it in the Options dialogue under Mail. "Spelling and Autocorrect". Then choose "Autocorrect". Note that, if you go in that way, you don't get the option to use formatted text only plain text.

You can also access via Word itself and this may be easier if you are wanting to include formatting.

Use is simple, enter the text you want to trigger the replacement in the left-hand box and the replacement text in the right.

To get formatted text, you have to be in an email or Word document, write what you want to appear and apply formatting, then select the formatted text before triggering the autocorrect dialogue. The formatted replacement will automatically be populated, just put in the shortcut you want.

Comment: Many thanks, I was able to find and amend what the previous employee created as well creating new text shortcuts. I now also have some very happy employees who can create their own text shortcuts.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the question answered if you feel that it helped so others can benefit in the future.